# Read Python Logging Log File in Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04, python-logging

## Environment

I am running code I found online and it uses the `logging` library to create logs. I am using python3.6.9 on Ubuntu 18.04. The code is a neural network Tensorflow code, in case that is somehow relevant.

## The Problem + More Info

When I use vim to open the log files produced it looks like they are in binary.
Using the `file` command in Ubuntu I see that the type of the file is "data".

In the code the logger is initiated using `logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)`
the file is being saved as a `.0` and `.1` files, i.e `events.out.tfevents.1600700600.mycomputername.21941.1`.

Please let me know any other information you need me to provide.
Thank you in advance for any help available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the file you open is not one generated by the python logging module because the configuration shown: `logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)` is just logging stuff to `stdout` not to a file

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I now see where the logs are actually printed out, cant believe I missed it... Thanks for explaining to me and taking me out of the thought loop I was in!